# show the selected index hide the other index in angular 6

Tags: angular

After displaying all the cards, By clicking on the card clicked card should be visible and other should be invisible.how could i do it?

selected.html

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let x of list; let i = index " style="padding:15px;">
   <div class="card ">
     <div class="card-body ">
      <img src="{{x.productImage}}" class=" rounded" (click)="display(x)" >
      <div>{{x.product_name}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
/*2nd div*/
<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let y of similar; let i = index " style="padding:15px;">
   <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-body " >
     <img src="{{y.productImage}}" class=" rounded"  >
     <div>{{y.product_name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

selected.ts

```
list:object;
  ngOninit{
      this.data.getList().subscribe(data => {
      this.list  = data;
  });

 display(x){
    this.data.getSimilar().subscribe(data => {
    this.similar  = data;
  });
   for(var i=indexNumber; i< this.list.length; i++){
     if (i==indexNumber || i==indexNumber-1){
       this.list[i].visible=false;
    }
     else{
      this.list[i].visible=true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If something is invisible, how will you click on it?

Comment: Your click event is having different name display(x) -> edisplay(). and then you have to implement show and hide logic as per your requirement.

Comment: can you create an stackblitz example ?

Comment: @PrabhatMaurya   By applying show and hide logic all cards are invisible but i want  clicked card should be visible  and other card should invisible

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngetz9 - i have created small app. i might help you

Comment: @KesavanR Thank you its worked

Comment: @ArchanaR post as a answer. Please hit as a accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use boolean flag to show and hide the other list cards. In your case x.hidden = true or false.

**app.component.ts**

```js
display(x){
    this.list.forEach((x) => x.hidden = !x.hidden);
    if(x) { x.hidden = false; }
  }
```

and in your **app.component.html**

```html
<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let x of list; let i = index " style="padding:15px;" [hidden]="x.hidden">
     <div class="card ">
       <div class="card-body ">
      <img src="{{x.productImage}}" class=" rounded" (click)="display(x)" >
      <div>{{x.product_name}} {{i}}</div>
   </div>
</div>

/*2nd div*/

   <div class="row ">
     <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let y of similar; let i = index " style="padding:15px;">
       <div class="card ">
         <div class="card-body " >
           <img src="{{y.productImage}}" class=" rounded" (click)="display()" >
           <div>{{y.product_name}}</div>
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

and created small app : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngetz9

**Updated:**
Just bind click event to 2nd row image and dont pass anything. Please find the display() updated code

Comment: now how to visible selected card and previous card  and other next card should be invisible by click

Comment: @ArchanaR click of visible card or document click ?

Comment: I want by clicking clicked card and previous card should be visible now only clicked card is visible

Comment: @ArchanaR i have update display() method and check stackblitz link as well. let me know if any issue

Comment: in the invisible place can we visible the other div cards?

Comment: @ArchanaR Yes. let me know if that required

Comment: in N+1 position i have to display the other div cards

Comment: please update code that will helpful to understand your problem

Comment: @ArchanaR - i have updated display method and bind the click event to second row it should work. stackblitz also updated. Please check

Answer (score 1):

> html

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let x of list; let i = index " style="padding:15px;">
   <div class="card" *ngIf="selectedIndex && selectedIndex==i">
     <div class="card-body ">
      <img src="{{x.productImage}}" class=" rounded" (click)="display(x)" >
      <div>{{x.product_name}}</div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div (click)="resetIndex()">Reset SelecetedIndex</div>
</div>
```

> component

```
elist:object;
selectedIndex:number;
ngOninit{
    this.selectedIndex=null;
    this.data.getList().subscribe(data => {
      this.list  = data;
    });
 }
display(x){
   this.selectedIndex=x;
   console.log(x)
}
resetIndex(){
    this.selectedIndex=null;
}
```

so by default every card will be shown , and you can reset the selected index.